# How to get automount and sshfs (osxfuse) working with yosemite

Tags: network, macos, ssh, automount

I'm currently trying to get Apple's automount working with osxfuse and sshfs.
The result should be that a specified folder gets automatically mounted if it is used.

**What I've done so far:**

- installed osxfuse and sshfs from the official packages
  (versions are osxfuse: 2.7.3 / sshfs 2.5.0)
- created a symlink `/sbin/mount_sshfs -> /usr/local/bin/sshfs`
- appended the following config line to /etc/auto_master : `/-    auto_ssh    -nosuid`
- created the /etc/auto_ssh config file:

  ```
  /mnt -fstype=sshfs,sshfs_debug,allow_other,idmap=user,follow_symlinks,max_read=65536,rw,nodev,cache=no,IdentityFile=/Users/myUsername/.ssh/sshfs remoteUser@remoteHost:/path/to/folder
  ```
- afterwards reload automount via : `sudo automount -cv`

If I now try to `cd` into `mnt` i get the following error:

```
bash: cd: /mnt: Operation not permitted
```

The console contains the following:

```
04/12/14 01:27:50,418 automountd[1965]: MOUNT  REQUEST: name=/mnt [] map=auto_ssh opts=nosuid path=/mnt direct=1
04/12/14 01:27:50,631 KernelEventAgent[69]: tid 54485244 received event(s) VQ_DEAD (32)
04/12/14 01:27:50,632 automountd[1965]: MOUNT  REPLY  : status=1, AUTOFS_DONE
04/12/14 01:27:50,632 automountd[1965]: mount of /mnt failed: Operation not permitted
```

Does anyone have any idea how to make this work, or what to try next?

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, if anyone else stumbles across this old question, the best guide I have found for mounting sshfs using apple's automounter is here -

http://virtuallyhyper.com/2013/07/mount-various-file-system-with-autofs-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/#mount-sshfs-with-autofs

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't require disabling System Integrity Protection, as cron jobs are still working in el captain:

```
$ crontab -e

*/5 * * * *  /usr/local/bin/sshfs 192.168.1.2:/etc /Users/xxx/temp/etc -o uid=$(id -u) -o gid=$(id -g) -o reconnect
```

Comment: Is your answer to disable System Integrity Protection or is this a new question?

Comment: This is just another way to achieve an automount behavior. This Works without disabling sip..

Comment: Ok, just clarifying. I've edited your answer to make it more clear.

Comment: When the volume is already mounted this throws an error`mount_osxfusefs: mount point /Users/xxx/temp/etc is itself on a OSXFUSE volume`. Is there a way to only run the command if it is unmounted?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke you can have simple bash script running in cron tab (example is for password connection, but you should get the idea) 

#!/bin/bash
umount /Users/shuib/Documents/mountFolder
echo "yourSSHpassword " | sshfs toho@drasha.site:/home/toho/draSha/Users/shuib/Documents/mountFolder -o password_stdin

Answer (score 3):

For macOS Mojave and latest version of osxfuse, this is the correct daemon file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>sysctl</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/Library/Filesystems/osxfuse.fs/Contents/Resources/load_osxfuse; /usr/sbin/sysctl -w vfs.generic.osxfuse.tunables.allow_other=1</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

`load_osxfuse` is now located at `/Library/Filesystems/osxfuse.fs/Contents/Resources/load_osxfuse` and the correct kernel parameter is `vfs.generic.osxfuse.tunables.allow_other`

More info at [osxfuse wiki](https://github.com/osxfuse/osxfuse/wiki/Mount-options)

Answer (score 2):

Update 2016-08-03: I found that installing SSHFS from https://osxfuse.github.io is stabler than the homebrew version, because of some old dependency (therefore this may improve in the future).

**CAVEAT: This connection is super fast when it works, but often has issues after terminated connects due e.g. wireless, standby.**

---

Assumes you have [Homebrew](http://brew.sh) installed (*make your life easier and get this first*)

## Installation of SSHFS

```
brew install sshfs
```

Check this folder to see installed file systems: `ls /Library/Filesystems`
If you don't see `osxfusefs.fs`, you need to install it.

Get Cask

```
brew tap caskroom/cask
```

Install OSXFUSE

```
brew cask install osxfuse
```

Alternatively instead of homebrew use the download versions from
https://osxfuse.github.io/

## SSHFS + OSXFUSE Now Installed. One more step...

`autofs` needs `mount_*` binaries.

`/usr/local/bin/sshfs` should be also available as `mount_sshfs`, so:

List your `mount_*`s with

```
compgen -c | grep ^mount
```

OR

```
ls /sbin | grep mount
```

If you do not see mount_sshfs, the you need to do this step. **This is a critical step because it is easily forgotten and may create headaches.**
As `/sbin` is on the system partition you'll need to [turn off SIP *and* remount the partition with the writable attribute](https://medium.com/@lightcone/how-do-i-modify-files-in-system-in-macos-catalina-3897194a6aa2).

In Recovery Mode open Terminal and turn off SIP and reboot:

```
csrutil disable
reboot
```

Once rebooted, remount the system volume:

```
sudo mount -uw /
```

Now you can create the proper symlink:

```
sudo ln -s $(which sshfs) /sbin/mount_sshfs
```

## Add Autostart at Boot Daemon in `/Library/LaunchDaemons/`

File could be called:

You need to run this at every boot for the kernel extension:

```
/bin/bash -c "/Library/Filesystems/osxfuse.fs/Contents/Resources/load_osxfuse; /usr/sbin/sysctl -w vfs.generic.osxfuse.tunables.allow_other=1"
```

So create a new service file:

```
/Library/LaunchDaemons/load.osxfusefs.tunables.plist
```

Contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>sysctl</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>-c</string>
        <string>/Library/Filesystems/osxfuse.fs/Contents/Resources/load_osxfuse; /usr/sbin/sysctl -w vfs.generic.osxfuse.tunables.allow_other=1</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Load with `launchctl` (launchd) for next boot, which is the Mac OS X version of `systemctl` (systemd)

```
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/load.osxfusefs.tunables.plist
```

## Setup auto_master and auto_sshfs

The following assumes you can ssh into your server with a secure key (no password required).

##/etc/auto_master

```
/mnt/sshfs                auto_sshfs       -nosuid
```

##/etc/auto_sshfs
You could use parameters that normally come after the `-o` in `sshfs -o`  depending on your situation.

- idmap=user: default setting. since your uid and gid is probably different across operating systems, you could just map the user used in the user@ip: to your local (client) user. The group will be ignored in this case (which means folders not owned by you yet grant you read permissions on the server-side group may not be readable locally--on the client side)

OR

- uid=YOURUSERID, gid=YOURGROUPID: just type id YOURUSER to get the numbers. This will just map all files from the mount to this user/group combination. This will allow you to read all files. I think any new files/folders you create will inherit the default umask settings for whichever folder you mount.
- allow-other: I use this, but is is risky because any user who browses the mount will view the mount using the credentials used when connecting.
- list all parameters with `man sshfs` and read see each parameter after every `-o`

replace:

- YOURUSER with your username and
- PRIVATEKEY to your key e.g. id_ed25519
- ip with your ip address or hostname

Contents
*Important is the parameter `reconnect`, otherwise whenever you loose connection (like go to sleep), Finder will crash.*

Replace

- $(id -u) with your actual id on client machine
- $(id -g) with your actual group id on client machine

*Unfortunately you cannot execute things in autofs like `id -u`*

```
NameOfMountThatGetsIgnored -fstype=sshfs,port=22,reconnect,uid=$(id -u),gid=$(id -g),follow_symlinks,allow_other,IdentityFile=/Users/YOURUSER/.ssh/PRIVATEKEY,volname="NameOfMount"     YOURUSER@ip:/path/on/server
```

## Test

```
df -Ph /path/to/mount
```

List mounted filesystems

```
lsvfs
```

List all mounts

```
mount
```

Comment: I've been trying to get this to work, but it seems like some recent changes in macOS make it more difficult than it should be. It is not possible to symlink sshfs into /usr/sbin/mount_sshfs. Possibly an issue with SIP? You don't happen to know a workaround, do you? (would rather not turn off SIP to make the modification, but I will if I have to; any way to get /usr/local/sbin/mount_sshfs to work?)

Answer (score 0):

I've went through all the automount guides I could find and have successfully completed the steps from [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/245009/24324) but in the end I got a hanging Finder and could not unmount via Terminal.

Therefore I would like to mention an alternative, less intrusive option: [Folder Actions](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_folder_actions.html).

In the past these were unreliable, so your mileage may vary, but for me (on Catalina) they work reliably so far (1 day in).

1. Open Script Editor.
2. Create a script with the following content:

```
on opening folder this_folder
    do shell script "/usr/local/bin/sshfs user@ipaddress:remote_path ~/mnt/volume_name -o volname=desired_volume_name"
end opening folder
```

3. Compile this script in the Script Editor (using the  icon)
4. Save this file in `~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts/` under any name you feel is descriptive.
5. Go to the parent folder that will contain the mounted volume. In above example that's `~/mnt`.
6. Right click on `~/mnt`, go to *Services* → *Folder Actions Setup...* → *Run Service* and:

   - Enable Folder Actions
   - Click on the ➕ sign in the right panel and add the script from step 4

Now everytime you open the folder `~/mnt`, the `sshfs` command will try to mount the remote volume under `~/mnt/desired_volume_name`.